# Re-Organize 1d buffer as a 2d array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am given a 1d buffer (`int buffer[100]`) of sufficient size. I need to re-organize the same memory as a 2d array. What i am trying to do is typecast it into a double pointer(`int ** p`) and then pass the pointer to the alloc function which will do the reorganizing. After the function returns, i need the statement `p[2][2]` to work.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void alloc(int ** buf, int r, int c)
{
    int **temp;
    temp=buf;
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        buf[i]=*(temp+i*c);
}
void main()
{
    int buffer[100];
    int **p=(int **)buffer;
    alloc(p, 4, 4);
    p[2][2]=10;
    printf("%d", p[2][2]);
}
```

The above code compiles successfully, but when i run the code i get an access violation upon execution of the statement

```
p[2][2]=10;
```

I'm failing to understand where the problem lies. Is there a problem with the alloc function? Or is the problem somehwere else?

Comment: 1d array does not become 2d just because you use it like that. your full code is wrong. you cannot turn 1d buffer 2d, what you can do is make an abstraction ( ex. a method) which takes row,col and returns an element from the 1D buffer, so to the client of that method, it looks like using a 2D array

Comment: Remove the `(int**)` cast you did in main() and recompile the code.  Now look at the compiler errors.  The errors mean what they say.  Casting doesn't magically make one type into another.

Comment: The problem is that `p` is a pointer to a pointer, not a 2D array. So when the compiler sees `p[2][2]`, the first thing it does is try to retrieve `p[2]` which it expects to be a `pointer to an int`. Let's call that pointer `q`. After the compiler retrieves `q`, it tries to retrieve `q[2]`, which it expects to be an `int`. However, since `q` is **not** a valid pointer, that causes an access violation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's examine your code to understand why it does not work.

Let's use a shorter buffer to understand what you are doing.

Let's say you have:

```
int buffer[9];
```

and you want to treat it like a 3x3 2D array. Memory used buffer:

```
buffer
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You want to create an `int** p` such that:

```
p[0]        p[1]        [p2]
|           |           |
v           v           v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In order to accomplish that, you have allocate memory to store `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and `p[2]`. That means, you need:

```
int** p = new int*[3];
p[0] = buffer;
p[1] = buffer + 3;
p[2] = buffer + 6;
```

Now, `p` as well as `p[0]`, `p[1]`, `p[2]` point to valid addresses. You can use the syntax `p[m][n]`.

In our code, you just assigned `p` to point to the same location as `buffer` and by using the statement

```
buf[i]=*(temp+i*c);
```

you are just using the memory held by `buffer` as holders of `int*`, which not only tramples the data in `buffer` but also makes the values of the pointers unpredictable.

Here's a working program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int buffer[100];
   int rows = 4;
   int cols = 10;
   int **p = new int*[rows];
   for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
   {
      p[i] = buffer + i*cols;
      printf("%p\n", p[i]);
      for ( int j = 0; j < cols; ++j )
      {
         p[i][j] = i*2 + j*3;
      }
   }
   printf("\n");

   for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < cols; ++j )
      {
         printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: @sph714 Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C, you can simply cast your array to the correct type:

```
void main() {
    int width = 10, height = 10;
    int buffer[width*height];
    int (*p)[width] = (int (*)[width])buffer;
    p[2][2]=10;
    printf("%d", p[2][2]);
}
```

or directly use a 2D array:

```
void main() {
    int width = 10, height = 10;
    int buffer[width][height];
    buffer[2][2]=10;
    printf("%d", buffer[2][2]);
}
```

This works, because 2D arrays in C are arrays of arrays. Thus the 2D array is an array of ten arrays with ten elements each, all stored sequentially in memory. The type `int (*)[width]` denotes the type of a pointer to one of these line arrays. So, when you do `p[2]`, you invoke pointer arithmetic which adds twice the size of the line array to the pointer before dereferencing it. This (indirectly) results in an `int*` to the first element of the third line array, on which you can again invoke the same pointer arithmetic to select the right element in the 2D array.

This won't work as seamlessly in C++ since array types have to have a compile time size in C++. C is much more flexible in that respect, allowing you to easily pass a 2D array of arbitrary size to a function:

```
void foo(int width, int height, int (*image)[width]);

void main() {
    int width = 10, height = 10;
    int buffer[width][height];
    foo(width, height, buffer);
}
```

Comment: @bruin No. I know only two ways to enable the `p[2][2]` indexing for runtime array sizes in C++: 1) Allocate a separate array for the line pointers (type `int**`) and initialize them to point at the individual lines in the 2D array. 2) Write a 2D array class that overloads the `[]` operator to return a line array pointer. In this case, the 2D array class would manage the buffer internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int buffer[100];
    int (*p)[4]=(int (*)[4])buffer;//int p[25][4]

    p[2][2]=10;
    printf("%d\n", p[2][2]);
    printf("%d\n", buffer[4*2+2]);//10
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: some explanation would be nice

Comment: re-organize the same memory as a 2d array by typecast.

Comment: In the answer, I mean. Comments are second-class citisens

Answer (score 0):

You can not *convert* 1D array to 2D. In fact, every multi-dimensional array is just a 1D/linear collection of cells, programming language creates the illusion of multi-dimensionality. You can create the same illusion, i.e. make an abstraction of a 1D array, so that it *looks* like a 2D (any any higher dimension)

You can do this:

```
#define ROW 10
#define COL 10

int arr[size]={1,2...}; //I am making it global, you can declare it anywhere

int& getValueFrom2DArray(int row,int col) // return type is a reference, so that you can assign
{
 if( row>= ROW || col >= COL)
  return -1; //treating -1 as sentinel value
 return array[ row*COL + col]; // convert 2D co-ordinates into 1D position
}

int main() //return type of main should be int, not void
{
   getValueFrom2DArray(2,2) = 10;
   cout<< getValueFrom2DArray(2,2)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```